# SequenceMatcher with custom comparison function

Tags: python

I tryed to execute the following code: (in python)

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as sm
class myint(int):
    def __cmp__(self , other):
        return 0
    def __eq__(self , other):
        return True

a = myint(1)
b = myint(2)  
c = myint(3)  
d = myint(1)
e = myint(2)
f = myint(3)
x = [a,b,c]
y = [f,e,d]
q = sm(None,x,y)
```

like you can see, in these code I tryed to use a custom comparison function, such that every two instances of myint are equal. but, when I use SequenceMatcher to compare twe lists of myint with the same length, I got an unexepted result:

```
>>> q.ratio()
1:  0.3333333333333333
```

instead of 1.0. I see that SequenceMatcher used the regular comparison between numbers instead of my comparison, although the lists were consisted of objects from type "myint".
How can I write the myint class such that SequenceMatcher will return 1.0, as exepted?
(or any other idea to use SequenceMatcher with custom comparison function)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem you've got is that:

```
y = [f,e,d]
```

should be

```
y = [d,e,f]
```

When you make this change, q.ratio() will return 1

```
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher as sm
>>> class myint(int):
...     def __cmp__(self , other):
...         return 0
...     def __eq__(self , other):
...         return True
... 
>>> a = myint(1)
>>> b = myint(2)  
>>> c = myint(3)  
>>> d = myint(1)
>>> e = myint(2)
>>> f = myint(3)
>>> x = [a,b,c]
>>> y = [d,e,f]
>>> q = sm(None,x,y)
>>> q.ratio()
1.0
```

Comment: Of course if the lists are identical the result will be 1.0. but according to my custom comparison function, **every** two elements in the lists are equal, so even if y = [f,e,d], the result should be 1.0.